# Can't access data() in QueryDocumentSnapshot

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get data from a document:

```
await db.collection("collectionName").doc(uid).get("root").data()
```

but I get: 'data is not a function',
which is strange, if I remove data()

```
await db.collection("collectionName").doc(uid).get("root")
```

I get the following object, and in fact I can see the **root** field in _fieldsProto

```
QueryDocumentSnapshot {
  _fieldsProto: { root: { mapValue: [Object], valueType: 'mapValue' } },
  _ref: DocumentReference {
    _firestore: Firestore {
      _settings: [Object],
.......
```

anyone knows how I could get fields from QueryDocumentSnapshot?

edit:

I realised I was calling data() before awaiting.
The working code is:

```
const snapshot await db.collection("collectionName").doc(uid).get()
console.log(snapshot.data())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest starting with the documentation to learn how to [get a document from Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#web-version-8_1).  `get()` returns a promise which becomes fulfilled when the query is complete.

```
db.collection("collectionName").doc(uid).get().then(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

As far as I can tell, you aren't using `then` or `await` to wait for the query to complete and get a hold of the snapshot in the callback.  That isn't an optional step - the query results are not available immediately.

Also, get() does not take any arguments.  If you want a field out of the snapshot, you have to dig into the snapshot provided by the callback.  If your document field is called "root", then just access it like any object property:

```
console.log(doc.data().root)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I am using await, I've just edited the question. I also tried get without string, but I get the same result

Comment: I understood my stupid mistake. I was using await, but I called data() on the same line, which clearly has to be called after awaiting